# Finding an Optimum way to avoid Overwriting of Key-Value in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to create an application that save the User Name and Contact Number using Shared Preferences.
The issue I am Facing is that when I am trying to add new Entry to it, the previous one is over written and I am stuck as I feel how can I manage this problem. I tried like 2 to 3 solutions found on Stack Overflow and None of them helped. 
Please do avoid the commented code as I am trying a lot more too.

This is the Activity where I am getting the Input from User and saving it to Shared Preferences

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.insert_button:
            String NAME = name.getText().toString();
         //   String CITY = city.getText().toString();
           // String EMAIL = email.getText().toString();
            String CONTACT = contact.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(nameKey , NAME);
           // editor.putString(emailKey, EMAIL);
           // editor.putString(cityKey, CITY);
            editor.putString(contactKey, CONTACT);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(500);
            name.setText("");
           // email.setText("");
           // city.setText("");
            contact.setText("");


            break;


        case R.id.view_button:

            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(mainKey, MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (sharedPreferences.contains(nameKey)) {
                name.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(nameKey, "Default Name"));
            }
             /*
            if (sharedPreferences.contains(emailKey)) {
                email.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(emailKey, "Default Email"));
            }
            if (sharedPreferences.contains(cityKey)) {
                city.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(cityKey, "Default City"));
            }  */
            if (sharedPreferences.contains(contactKey)) {
                contact.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(contactKey, "Default Contact"));
            }

            break;

        case R.id.home_button:

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            break;


    }

}
```

And i am accessing it in other activity.

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(mainKey, MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (sharedPreferences.contains(nameKey)) {
                name_tv.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(nameKey, "Default Name"));

            }
           /*
            if (sharedPreferences.contains(emailKey)) {
                email_tv.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(emailKey, "Default Email"));
            }
            if (sharedPreferences.contains(cityKey)) {
                city_tv.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(cityKey, "Default City"));
            }*/
            if (sharedPreferences.contains(contactKey)) {
                contact_tv.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(contactKey, "Default Contact"));

            }
            Toast.makeText(Home_Activity.this, "Recent Value Shown..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Now i need to loop the new Inserted data in the name_tv and contact_tv, but the data is getting overwritten.
Can you guys help..?
Please suggest me an optimum way..!!

Comment: General comment: Your app is ideally targeted towards one expected user, the owner of the Android phone.  Most of the time, your app should just have a handful of keys which it needs to write to shared preferences.  If you current logic is that you plan to keep on generating new keys indefinitely, then you might want to consider using a SQLite database for storage instead of shared preferences.  SQLite will scale much better regarding storing arbitrary amounts of data.

Comment: I can feel your point...What about sending the data which I am fetching from user to Firebase and then Displaying it?? But still how can I overcome this issue if I target Shared Preferences only..!!

Comment: Maybe that would work...I don't know your architecture.  But the symmetric thing to a cloud based database like Firebase locally on your phone would be something like SQLite IMO, not shared prefs.

Comment: Ok..If I am unable to resolve it with Shared Preferences....I'll go with SQLite..!! Thanks for your Help..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences putStringSet / getStringSet, to keep the same name+contact pair together, merge them into a single string with some divider.

ADDING:

```
String nameAndContact = MAME + "|" + CONTACT; // you need to filter out your divider from the original strings
Set<String> info = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("info", new HashSet<String>());
info.add(nameAndContact);
sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("info" , info).apply();
```

READING:

```
Set<String> info = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("info", new HashSet<String>());
for (String nameAndContact : info) {
    String[] parts = info.split("|");
    Log.i("pair: name=" + parts[0] + ", contact=" + parts[1]);
}
```